# How to return spawned process exit code in Expect script?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, expect

I use expect for running test scripts.
Tests return success/failure through exit code. But expect return equivalent exit code.
How to make expect return proper exit status?

My tests are sql scripts run with *psql* (postgresql command processor).
Since psql doesn't allow to specify database password as a command line parameter, *expect scripts* do that.

So, my expect script looks like:

```
spawn $SPAWN_CMD
expect {
        -re "Enter password for new role:" {
                send "$PWPROMPT\n"
                exp_continue
        } -re "Enter it again:" {
                send "$PWPROMPT\n"
                exp_continue
        } -re "Password(.*)" {
                send "$PASSWORD\n"
                exp_continue
        } -re "Password(.*):" {
                send "$PASSWORD\n"
                exp_continue
        } eof
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're already waiting for the `eof` at the end of your loop, you just need to use `wait` and `catch` the result:

```
spawn true
expect eof
catch wait result
exit [lindex $result 3]
```

Exits with 0.

```
spawn false
expect eof
catch wait result
exit [lindex $result 3]
```

Exits with 1.

Comment: Hmm..
`[21:43:30] ~> expect <<< "spawn true; expect eof; catch wait result; exit [lindex $result 3]"; echo $?` outputs `3` for me

Comment: @sasha.sochka If you type it like that $result gets interpreted by the shell rather than expect. Put the input in single quotes, or escape the $.