# Expect: How to get the exit code from spawned process

Tags: expect

I am not quite sure if it a good idea to create a new Thread or "reopen" [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299502/how-to-return-spawned-process-exit-code-in-expect-script) 3-year old Thread, if you think it's better to reopened it, please excuse my spam in this Forum but I have the same Problem and don't get a solution out of the information of the thread. At the Moment I had a script that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set pass [lindex $argv 0]
spawn <CMD>

expect {
  -re "Password: " {
    send "$pass\r"
  }

expect eof
catch wait result
}
exit [lindex $result 3]
```

but wenn I execute this Script I get the error

```
can't read "result": no such variable
    while executing
"lindex $result 3"
    invoked from within
"exit [lindex $result 3]"
    (file "./call_tests.exp" line 13)
```

I already found out that probably the problem is that the SSH-Session is already closed when I try to read the exit code. But I started yesterday to understand the expect-command so I am a complete newbie and I would very thanks full if someone can help me out.
best regards
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write like this:

```
expect {
  -re "Password: " {
    send "$pass\r"
  }
}
expect eof

catch wait result
exit [lindex $result 3]
```

or this:

```
expect {
  -re "Password: " {
    send "$pass\r"
    exp_continue
  }

  eof {
    catch wait result
  }
}
exit [lindex $result 3]
```

According to expect's man page:

> - `expect [[-opts] pat1 body1] ... [-opts] patn [bodyn]`
>
>   waits until one of the patterns matches the output of a  spawned
>   process,  a  specified time period has passed, or an end-of-file
>   is seen.  If the final body is empty, it may be omitted.
>   Patterns from the most recent `expect_before` command are  implicitly  used  before  any  other patterns.  Patterns from the most
>   recent `expect_after` command are implicitly used after any  other
>   patterns.
>
>   If  the  arguments  to  the entire expect statement require more
>   than one line, all the arguments may be *braced* into one so  as
>   to  avoid  terminating  each line with a backslash.  In this one
>   case, the usual Tcl substitutions will occur despite the braces.

Comment: Maybe I am a little late but I would like to thank you for this explanation